# Prevent the cell from expanding to the size of the monitor size when highlighted or double clicked in a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've applied text wrapping to my cells but every time I open my cells, it expands. I hate that actually, how can I stop doing this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to prevent horizontal expansion of the cell in edit mode is to insert line breaks at the end of the every line in the text so that line length does not exceed cell width. This may not be practical in most use cases.